# Why does Zero have such a strong reaction to Shizuka Hio's voice?

Tags: vampire-knight

In Episode 12 of the *Vampire Knight* anime series, Zero encounters Shizuku Hio, the woman who turned him into a vampire. Even before she tries to compel him, he is shown as experiencing a strong physical reaction to her voice. It is clear that he already knew that she was there, so he shouldn't have been surprised to hear her.

Why does he have that reaction? Does her voice have a compulsion before she tries to actively compel him? Is it due to some sort of bond he has with her? Or is there another reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it was what you said, a bond that was made due to Shizuka biting and turning Zero into a vampire.

During one episode (I'm not sure what episode), Zero has figured out that she must be Shizuka. Maria taunts Zero to pull the trigger, but he discovers he is unable to due to the bond between them. And it is said that once a human was bitten by a vampire, that vampire becomes his/her master and that human can be controlled by his/her master (like when Shizuka froze him when she was about to drink Yuki's blood).